# Stripe payment intent search api throwing error

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent, stripe-api-php

I am getting an error:call to undefined method stripe\paymentintent::search()

The code reference url is on [search stripe payment intents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/search?lang=php) using php library.

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_51KgTvKAFnFm5ESP8EPiYuUOkkuXT2SXWKa6kRcmLRIn14Q2QllFSibG6VLyejUNnigCagqttfLfrjvcFZTmZtuY000kcoaH4tS');
$stripe->paymentIntents->search(['query' => 'status:\'succeeded\' AND metadata[\'order_id\']:\'6735\'',]);
```

Comment: From the error `stripe\paymentintent::search()`, it appears that there might be a typo. Can you confirm that the request is `$stripe->paymentIntents->search` instead of `$stripe->paymentIntent->search`